# 3rd party DLL throws exception from IDisposable finalizer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

My application relies on a poorly-written, closed-source, unsupported 3rd-party DLL (don't ask).

I'm trying to work with a class from that DLL that implements `IDisposable`, but the finalizer likes to throw exceptions quite often.

A very simple example:

```
using (var badObj = new BadClass(path)){
     // do work
}

// not actually doing manual GC in real code...
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); // <-- Exception
```

Is there *any* way to recover from this without crashing the application?

Comment: Is it OK if the finalizer is never run? E.g., is `Dispose` enough?

Comment: You could intentionally leak memory and root the object. You could decompile and modify the DLL. Perhaps the exception is from "disposing" twice? You could not call Dispose() and assume the finalizer is going to do that. You could perhaps use reflection to modify private state to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the assembly. [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/), great tool!

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with the finalizer never running at all, assuming the call to `Dispose` is sufficient to clean things up, you can instruct the garbage collector to never run the finalizer with [`GC.SuppressFinalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.suppressfinalize?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_GC_SuppressFinalize_System_Object_).